# What is the correct way to create a translatable in four languages website logo with slogan?

Tags: 7, media

What is the correct way to create a translatable in four languages website logo with slogan? 
I am thinking  of creating a custom content type which will be populated in View block. Which when will be inserted in logo region. 
Are there any other approaches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you already using the [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module? The package contains the 'Variable translation' module which allows you to make certain variables language dependent. Since the site logo is also stored in the variables (`theme_settings['logo_path']` if I'm not mistaken) you can make that variable language dependent as well.

If you're not using the i18n module (and you're not going to need it soon), I suppose you can also switch between logo images in your theme's template.php.

I wouldn't recommend creating a node type for it. In my experience, whenever you're considering to create a node type that is meant to have a specific number of nodes, there probably is a better solution for what you're doing.

Comment: Fantastic, exact what I was looking for

Comment: Could either of you please elaborate how you did this? I am trying to get different logos to show up on the the page based on the language. I enabled the module as this suggested, and I now have the admin area to manage the variables, but now what? Thanks.

Comment: This is from http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/50337/7641 : go to configuration->Multilingual settings->variables (tab)->Theme settings. check the boxes. Then go to your theme and set a logo for each language.

Comment: Hey Marc, I think you should include that last comment here to further improve your interesting answer ...