# How do I display multilingual logos in D7?

Tags: 7, media, i18n-l10n

I have read almost every tutorial on the net about how to setup multilingual logos. Yet, I cannot get anything to work.

How do I get multilingual logos to display in D7? I have added

```
$conf['i18n_variables'] = array(
    'logo_path',
    'theme_XXX_settings',
);
```

I have also uploaded using the form for the theme settings while in the langauge of the logo I want to display. All languages are set to whatever file I upload last.

Do I need to use a different variable in the conf array? Do I need to print a different variable other than $logo in the theme?

Can someone who's done this give some very specific instructions or provide a link to a recent d7 tutorial?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For D7, this is very painless.

In i18n, enable 'Variable Translation' module. To do so, be sure to have at least variable 7.x.2.x, else this module is not available. Here is the text from the module page:

```
Multilingual variables that switch language depending on page language.
Requires: Internationalization (enabled), Locale (enabled), Variable     
(enabled), Variable store (7.x-2.x) (incompatible with version 7.x-1.2),
Variable realm (7.x-2.x) (incompatible with version 7.x-1.2)
```

After that, go to:

configuration->Multilingual settings->variables (tab)->Theme settings. check the boxes. Then go to your theme and set a logo for each language.

That's it!